# How can I access to the index of a variable in 'for' loop

Tags: python-3.7

How do I access the index i and j in a `for` loop?

```
mu_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
mu_2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
mu_3 = [9, 10, 11, 12]
mu_4 = [13, 14, 15, 16]


som = 0
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(i+1, 5):
        r = (mu_i - mu_j)
        som = som + r
```

I want to get this output:

```py
som = ((mu_1 - mu_2) + (mu_1 - mu_3) + (mu_1 - mu_4) +
       (mu_2 - mu_3) + (mu_2 - mu_4) +
       (mu_3 - mu_4))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to ask is how to use indices `i` and `j` to refer to your `mu_n` lists. As per the code below, you could add all lists into another list, and index into it.

#### However, you cannot subtract lists in Python.

***Note*!** : This won't work because the `-` (subtraction) operation is not supported for `list` types.

```py
mu = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
      [5, 6, 7, 8],
      [9, 10, 11, 12],
      [13, 14, 15, 16]]

som = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(i+1, 4):
        r = (mu[i] - mu[j])
        som = som + r
```

#### Finally

You might benefit from knowing that indices in Python start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve, but you can use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to iterate over an iterable together with its indices.

```
for i, x in enumerate([1, 5, 13, 6]):
    # Here, `i` is the items index and `x` the item itself
    pass
```

Comment: I want to loop on the i and j in my variable mu_ from 1 to 4